# How can I install Tor from the source code in the Git repository?

Tags: source-code

It is sometimes desirable to compile Tor from [source](https://git.torproject.org/tor.git), and perhaps run an unreleased version (e.g., to test the latest changes, use new features unavailable in the latest release, etc.). What is the procedure for doing so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To compile and install Tor from git follow these steps:

**Step 0**: Make sure you have `git`, a working "C compiler" and "GNU make" installed on your linux box. You also need `libevent-dev` and `libssl-dev` libraries before you start.

If you're on debian/ubuntu type:

```
 sudo apt-get install git build-essential automake libevent-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
```

- **Step 1**: Clone Tor from git.torproject.org

  `git clone https://git.torproject.org/tor.git`
- **Step 2**: `cd tor`
- **Step 3**: run `./autogen.sh`
- **Step 4**: run `./configure` or `./configure --disable-asciidoc` if you don't want to build the manpages.
  (See 'note' if you get error at this step)
- **Step 5**: run `make`
- **Step 6** (optional): run `make install`

***Note***: If you have problems finding libraries at *step 4* try the following instead:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" \ ./configure
```

or

```
./configure --with-libevent-dir=/usr/local
```

And if you have mysterious `autoconf` failures while linking openssl,
consider setting your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the openssl lib directory.

For example: `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/your_username/lib`.

see [INSTALL](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/INSTALL) for more details.

Comment: I very rarely make install at the end. Once I've run make, I have a src/or/tor binary and I can just run it in place. That way I don't have to worry about smearing anything over my filesystem.

Comment: I added "make install" just to fit the question. Maybe it'd be better to change the question to "How to compile Tor from git?" and remove "make install"?

Comment: Your INSTALL link points to the latest commit, which is not very helpful.

Comment: Is there an instruction how to run it with systemd?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** (after Roger Dingledine's comment):

Please, *do not use the "--enable-bufferevents" feature for stable installations*. It's not mature yet.

The --enable-bufferevents option has not ever worked. It is a partial feature that needs somebody to finish it.

---

```
./configure --disable-asciidoc
```

From changelog:

> Tor can now optionally build with the "bufferevents" buffered IO
>         backend provided by Libevent 2. To use this feature, make sure you
>         have the latest possible version of Libevent, and pass the
>         --enable-bufferevents flag to configure when building Tor from
>         source. This feature will make our networking code more flexible,
>         let us stack layers on each other, and let us use more efficient
>         zero-copy transports where available.

Comment: What are the "standard" build options? That is, what build options would yield a binary that's closest to the released binary? Where can that information be found?

Comment: @mirimir Good question. I read the script './configure' to realize all the options and its defaults values.

Comment: Yes, there are many options. Maybe I'm being obtuse. If there are options with defaults, the standard build obviously uses the defaults, right? But even so, I'd like confirmation from someone knowledgeable.

Comment: Alas, the --enable-bufferevents option has not ever worked. It is a partial feature that needs somebody to finish it. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Git source is really easy stuff for install tor. But I want to tell the easiest alternative way for installing tor from official tor source code. This following commands for Centos. If you're using other Linux, install libevent-devel, groupinstall 'Development Tools' from your default package manager(apt-get or any other).

root @ Centos.

- Step 1:`wget https://dist.torproject.org/tor-0.4.3.4-rc.tar.gz`
- Step 2:`tar -xf tor-0.4.3.4-rc.tar.gz` and `mv tor-0.4.3.4-rc tor`
- Step 3:`sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
- Step 4:`yum install libevent-devel`
- Step 5:`cd tor`
- Step 6:`./configure`
- Step 7:`make`
- Step 8:`make install`
- Step 9:run `tor`

I hope this answer will helps you.

Comment: Tor has a Git repository. You can find it at https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/

Comment: I could complete all steps successfully. But on running STEP 9 run tor. It runs tor but browser does not opens. Plesse guide