# JAP/JonDo uses SocksPort in Tor v0.2.4.23 built from git repo, but not in corresponding binary from Tor Project repo for Ubuntu trusty; why?

Tags: socks, jondonym

I'm exploring the possibility of tunneling JAP/JonDo through Tor, working in Ubuntu 14.04.1 x64 VMs in VirtualBox. The JonDo client has an option to use a SOCKS proxy. JAP/JonDo connects through `SocksPort 9050`, using the `tor-0.2.3.25-1` binary installed using `tor_0.2.3.25-1_amd64.deb` from [the saucy repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/tor/download/).

But the JonDo client does not connect through `SocksPort 9050` using Ubuntu binaries for `Tor v0.2.4.19` (from Ubuntu 12.04 aka saucy repository), `Tor v0.2.4.20` (from Ubuntu 14.04 aka trusty repository), or `Tor v0.2.4.23` (latest stable Tor release from [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/tor?dist=trusty) for trusty).

However, the JonDo client does connect just fine through SocksPort 9050, using Tor releases `tor-0.2.4.20` or `tor-0.2.4.23`, built in Ubuntu 14.04.1 x64 from [the Tor git repo](https://git.torproject.org/tor.git). I built as described in [How can I install Tor from the source code in the Git repository?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-can-i-install-tor-from-the-source-code-in-the-git-repository), except that I specified v0.2.4.23:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential automake libevent-dev libssl-dev
git clone https://git.torproject.org/tor.git
cd tor
git checkout tor-0.2.4.23
./autogen.sh
./configure --disable-asciidoc
make
sudo make install
```

I used no other custom build flags. And I haven't yet tested anything from the `v0.2.5` branch.

Why might the JonDo client be unable to use SocksPorts in the latest stock Ubuntu binaries, but work with corresponding local builds, and also with the `tor-0.2.3.25-1` Ubuntu binary?

Comment: It may be one of the build flags. Check how the binary from Tor Project repo for Ubuntu trusty was built.