# How to build a modified Tor browser bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, development

How to build a Tor browser bundle with a modified version of Tor?

I've some changes on Tor source code that I'd like to try for research reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You may look at following information from Tor:

> Building the bundle
>
> We use Gitian to ensure that byte-for-byte reproducible packages can
>   be built from our source repository by anyone. To re-build the bundle,
>   check out the Tor Browser builder repository and see the README.build
>   for instructions. You may also find the Tor Browser Hacking intro
>   document useful for learning about the build system and our
>   development processes.

For details you may click the following link: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser-details.html.en#build

Comment: This link gives details about the building process in general. I'm looking for a more clear steps that helps me to build the bundle with a modified Tor source code.

Comment: @Flora9, Dear, You may look at following Q&A, it may or may not help you, but worth looking at. https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-can-i-install-tor-from-the-source-code-in-the-git-repository

Answer (score 0):

Well to start, Tor is simple a modified version of Firefox.  First I would go about obtaining the Tor control plugin that the tor browser uses.  Then I would download the Vanilla firefox and add the plugin.  Lastly, I would get the tor server binaries (they are under ../Tor/ when you dl the browser).

Set Firefox settings to use a proxy at 127.0.0.1:9050.  Tor uses a socks5 protocol to communicate with your browser if I am not mistaken.

Comment: This could work before the release of Tor Browser Bundle where you have more than the browser and the stand alone Tor.