# Error installing Tor on my Mac

Tags: source-code, error, mac

I'm trying to install Tor on my Mac but it shows the following error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
  CCLD     src/or/tor
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSL_set_session_secret_cb", referenced from:
      _tor_tls_new in libor-crypto.a(tortls.o)
      _tor_tls_session_secret_cb in libor-crypto.a(tortls.o)
  "_EVP_aes_128_ctr", referenced from:
      _aes_new_cipher in libor-crypto.a(aes.o)
  "_CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric", referenced from:
      _tor_set_openssl_thread_id in libor-crypto.a(crypto.o)
  "_CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback", referenced from:
      _crypto_early_init in libor-crypto.a(crypto.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [src/or/tor] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you trying to manually build from the source code?

Comment: yeah!! I am trying to build from the source code!

Answer (score 2):

This is a linker error, meaning you're (probably) missing a library that's required for Tor to build properly.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_SSL_set_session_secret_cb", referenced from: _tor_tls_new in libor-crypto.a(tortls.o)
```

These mean that the Tor code is trying to use `_SSL_set_session_secret_cb`, `_EVP_aes_128_ctr`, `_CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric`, and `_CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback`, but can't find them. This means they must reside in some code - probably a library - that either isn't on your machine, or is in the "wrong" place. (i.e. A place where the compiler doesn't know to look.)

A quick Google shows that they're part of OpenSSL, which suggests that `libssl` isn't present.

Assuming you're on Ubuntu (or another Debian-based system), you can following the instructions described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL) to either install the library, or check it's in the correct place.

To install on Mac, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874728/openssl-install-issue-to-mac

**Edit:**

In fact, full details of the libraries that are required are included in a previous (Ubuntu-related) thread: [How can I install Tor from the source code in the Git repository?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-can-i-install-tor-from-the-source-code-in-the-git-repository)

Comment: I am on a mac and I really can't get the help!

Comment: I'll attempt to add some Mac instructions. (Sorry for not clearly reading the title... )

Comment: As an aside, is there a particular reason why you're building from source instead of just using one of the packages?

Comment: Nothing just want anonymity for all my browsers! So building it from the core and I am getting screwed up!

Comment: Okay, instead of building from source, you could a) install the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#macosx), or b) [install Tor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en) itself and then configure your other browsers to use it as a SOCKS proxy. Note that option a) is very much the recommended way of doing things. (Trying to configure another browser, e.g. Chrome, to be completely anonymous is [difficult](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser)... )