# how to set up a two hop tor since I don't need strong anonymous

Tags: configuration

I am finding the following link, but it's quit old, and not sure whether it's usable. Anybody knows how to use 2 hop?

https://grepular.com/Tor_Circuits_with_Two_Hops_on_Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not interested in remaining anonymous then a VPN or standalone proxy would probably suit your needs better. (It'd probably be faster, for a start.)

The instructions you've linked to *are* a bit old, and it might be easier and cleaner to build from the source directly, rather than using the package manager. To build from source, have a look at [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-can-i-install-tor-from-the-source-code-in-the-git-repository) thread.

Finally, what you're trying to do has been discussed in the past. [This](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/how-to-decrease-number-of-tor-hops?rq=1.) thread concludes that it's probably a bad idea. It also mentions the `AllowSingleHopCircuits` config option, but that requires you to connect to a relay with `AllowSingleHopExits` set, and there probably aren't many of them...